# Another Repainting Error in PineScript v4 : Adaptive Least Squares Moving Average

Tags: pine-script

Thanks to this forum I was able to update this to version 4, but for the record, the version 2 was in fact culprit in repainting, as I double checked. This is one of Alex Grover's earliest algorithms, though ironically one of the best by far, but it does in fact repaint, when few of his do. I don't know how much use it will be when it is invariably forced to lag by fixing the repaint, but he's never produced another adaptive LSMA, it's the only adaptive one I know of. So I'm willing to use a reduced effectiveness version of it, if anyone here is able to identify what's causing it to repaint.
I suspect it's the barindex, but before I kneecap it, i'd like to hear opinions on how changing that would play out I suppose.

```
    study("Adaptive Least Squares", overlay=true)
    src = input(title="EMA Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
    length = input(500)
    smooth = input(1.5)
    //
    alpha = pow(tr / highest(tr, length), smooth)
    m(a, prevVal) =>
    alpha * a + (1 - alpha) * nz(prevVal, a)
    //
    x = bar_index
    y = src
    x_ = 0.0
    x_ := m(x, x_[1])

    y_ = 0.0
    y_ := m(y, y_[1])
    //
    dx = abs(x - x_)
    dy = abs(y - y_)

    mx = 0.0
    mx := m(dx, mx[1])
    my = 0.0
    my := m(dy, my[1])
    //

    xx = 0.0
    xx := m(x * x, xx[1])

    xy = 0.0
    xy := m(x * y, xy[1])

    yy = 0.0
    yy := m(y * y, yy[1])

    a1 = pow(2 / alpha + 1, 2) * xy - (2 / alpha + 1) * x_ * (2 / alpha + 1) * y_
    b1 = sqrt((pow(2 / alpha + 1, 2) * xx - pow((2 / alpha + 1) * x_, 2)) * (pow(2 / alpha + 1, 2) * yy 
    - pow((2 / alpha + 1) * y_, 2)))
    r = a1 / b1
    //
    a = r * (my / mx)
    b = y_ - a * x_
    reg = x * a + b
    //
    plot(reg, color=color.red, transp=0)
```

Comment: I got it to not repaint with this slight change, but of course the change made the trajectory drastically different. Not sure about what would give it a comparable degree of smoothing compared to the repainting version x = close
y = close[1]
x_ = 0.0
x_ := m(x, x_[1])

Comment: Any indicator using `close` will repaint in the realtime bar, and contrary to your title, it's not an error—just normal behavior in the realtime bar for a study since it recalculates on each realtime bar update. So what's your purpose here? You don't want the line to move on the chart in the realtime bar? You want alerts to be reliable? See here for a discussion and illustration of your options: https://www.tradingview.com/script/s8kWs84i-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-NOT-using-security/